# Bootstrap 4: How to get a div centered in mobile view under buttons?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm busy with a navbar that collapses in mobile, so far so good. In desktop mode, it looks like I want, but in mobile view, I want the div with id `plaatsen` to be positioned under the menu buttons and both in width 100%.

So like this:

```
              Logo
```

---

```
Button 1    Button 2    Button 3
```

---

```
            plaatsen
```

---

Code:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-center">
    <div class="container" style="padding: 0px;">
        <a class="navbar-brand d-flex mr-auto" href="<?php echo $this->url('home'); ?>" target="_self" style="background-color: red;width:350px;">
            <img src="<?= $this->basePath('img/logo.png') ?>"/>
        </a>
        <div id="buttons">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#button1" aria-controls="button1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="margin-top: 12px;">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#button2" aria-controls="button2" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="margin-top: 12px;">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#button3" aria-controls="button3" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="margin-top: 12px;">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="button2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto w-100 justify-content-center" style="background-color: green;">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <form class="navbar-form mx-auto" role="search">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="border-color: white;">Submit</button>                
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-md-column ml-auto w-30 justify-content-end">
            <div style="text-align: right;" id="plaatsen">
            plaatsen
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  " id="button1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav  ">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Bedrijfsvermelding<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>                        
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?= $this->basePath('inloggen') ?>">Inloggen<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the question. It's hard to tell from the code what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want the 3 buttons next to each other and the div with plaatsen under it in full width (in mobile view)

Comment: "plaasten" and all the other stuff like "Bedrijfsvermelding", or just "plaasten" by itself?

Comment: Just plaatsen, the rest is collapsing after a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you need to do a couple of things:

1. Add the classes `flex-column flex-lg-row` to the container. The first will make it behave like a flex column by default and the second will make it behave like a flex row from the large (lg) screen size and up.
2. Add the classes `text-white text-lg-right py-2 py-lg-0` to the "plaatsen" div and remove `style="text-align: right;"`. The `text-lg-right` will align the text to the right on `lg` screens or larger. `py-*` is for controlling vertical padding (see reference link below for more info).
3. Remove the unnecessary classes on the parent div of the "plaatsen" div. I marked those in the snippet below by adding "NONE" to each.
4. Change the spacing classes for the navbrand to `mr-0 mr-lg-auto`. Again, see the reference link below for more info on spacing classes.

Here's the working code snippet (click the "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-center">
    <div class="container flex-column flex-lg-row" style="padding: 0px;">
        <a class="navbar-brand d-flex mr-0 mr-lg-auto" href="#" target="_self" style="background-color: red;width:350px;">
            <img src="https://placehold.it/30"/>
        </a>
        <div id="buttons">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#button1" aria-controls="button1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="margin-top: 12px;">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#button2" aria-controls="button2" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="margin-top: 12px;">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#button3" aria-controls="button3" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="margin-top: 12px;">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="button2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto w-100 justify-content-center" style="background-color: green;">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <form class="navbar-form mx-auto" role="search">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="border-color: white;">Submit</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-md-column ml-autoNONE w-30NONE justify-content-endNONE">
            <div class="text-white text-lg-right py-2 py-lg-0" id="plaatsen">
                plaatsen
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="button1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Bedrijfsvermelding<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>                        
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link pr-0" href="#">Inloggen<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Reference regarding responsive spacing classes in Bootstrap 4:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/